# Calculator Bomb

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

So, I need your help.

I got home after a long day and found a calculator roughly taped to my door. However, there was something much more disturbing attached to that calculator. It was some kind of black device with a blinking red 12 on it. There was also a note which I read.

> Hello... In order to live, you must defuse the bomb by making the calculator show the number 212. However, you only have 12 key presses to do it, including the = key at the end. Don't try to enter your house through a window or opening a door, or any other way, or the bomb will go off. Don't call the police or anyone to help, either. This message contains *no* hints, so it's a waste of time looking for them. In addition, this calculator is modified so that you can't press a number when there's a number and no operation in (for example, you can't press the 6 key if the calculator shows 89 with no equation.)

Easy. I was about to hit 212 Enter when I noticed, the 2 and 1 keys were broken. So were so many keys, that, it's easier to list the keys that *weren't broken.*

Keys remaining: $0, 4, 7,+,  -, x^2, 10^x, =$

Note: The $x^2$ and $10^x$ keys give their result immediately, without requiring another key press.

The calculator currently displays the number $5$.

One last thing: You *must* hit the = sign at the end.

Good luck. I definitely hope you have it, because I need some right now.

Also, the tag says no computers, but feel free to pull out an actual calculator and give it a go. Just no computer *programs.*

If you have any questions on how certain buttons work, feel free to ask me in comments.

CLARIFICATION: The calculator has no memory function, so you can't do equations 'on the side' like squaring a number separately, then adding that number to the main total.

Extra Credit: Can you do it without the + key?

Comment: No parentheses?

Comment: No parentheses.

Comment: "Don't call the police or anyone to help, either"... heh heh heh

Comment: I don't think I understand how this calculator is supposed to work; it certainly isn't the same as any real calculator I've ever used. Is the idea that when you hit the "squared" button it first of all behaves as if you have pressed the = key, and _then_ squares the result?

Comment: Do you mean 5 as in already typed in, or a previous answer? (Basically can you add stuff to make it like 54 or something?)

Comment: Also, could you clarify what the $10^x$ button does? Is it used for entering exponents (so e.g. if you hit 4 then $10^x$ then 7 you get the number 40000000) as on actual calculators, or does it actually compute 10 to the power of whatever number is currently shown on the display, or something else?

Comment: Wow, I'm getting a lot of comments. Addressing them 1 at a time.

Comment: 1. 5 is already typed in. You cannot add numbers to it right now (because you can't press a number in when there's an already existing number in with no equation.) 2. $10^x$ computes 10 to the power of whatever number is in the display __at that moment__, as does $x^2$ (except it squares the current number). 3. The calculator is like that to make it harder :^)

Comment: Nope, still don't understand. Suppose the display says 5. Then I hit + and then 4; the display still says 4, right? So now I hit the $x^2$ key. An actual calculator will square the 4 currently displayed and get 16. That is also what you have just said it does. But I think your _intention_ is something else: that when you hit that key it will "finish" the current calculation as if you'd pressed =, getting 9, before squaring. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I see what you're saying now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OP has clarified the somewhat unorthodox behaviour of the calculator; my earlier answer, preserved below, no longer applies but we can do something else instead.]

Do this:

> + 4 + 7 sq - 4 4 =

That will

> add 4+7 to our initial 5, getting 16; square it, getting 256; subtract 44, getting 212.

We have used

> 9 keypresses in total.

If we need to use the full 12 keypresses, we can

> follow up with + 0 = which of course changes nothing.

---

**Old answer, applicable to real calculators**

I think I can do it in 11 key presses:

> sq - 4 - 7 = sq + 4 sq =

So

> after squaring the calculator shows 25; we subtract 4 and 7 to get 14; we square to get 196; we add 4^2=16 to get 212.

If we need to use *exactly* 12 key presses we can

> press = after subtracting 4.

Comment: 1. It is stated that you need to hit the = sign at the end.

Comment: I did. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: and 2. It wouldn't be possible to add 4^2 at the end, because the ^2 would square the entire thing, getting a very large number.

Comment: Really? Not on any calculator I've used.

Comment: Huh. I'll reword the question to include that.

Comment: (I just tried exactly my sequence of keystrokes using the calculator Microsoft supply with Windows 10, and got the required result.)

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu PEMDAS does exponents before addition

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter what standard mathematical notation means -- but it does matter what this sort of calculator actually does. And what they do is what I said :-).

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu I think he means $196+4^2$

Comment: Nice! I had a different answer but this is definitely valid.

Answer (score 4):

Going off of Gareth's answer a bit, for extra credit (no '+' key), we can try

> - 7 sq sq sq - 4 4 =

Which works (I think) because

> $5-7=-2$
>  $(((-2)^2)^2)^2=256$
>  $256-44=212$

and uses

> 8 keypresses in total.

For exactly 12 keypresses,

> We can follow with - 0 0 = which changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here goes.

We start with $5$,

> $+70+70+77=$ somehow has 10 key presses!!!

And,

> $5+70+70+77=212$

I did it.

Comment: That equals 222