# Puzzle House Side Puzzle #1: Swimming Swans?

Tags: riddle

So, to get to the puzzle stated in [Puzzle House #1: Entrance Hall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72818/puzzle-house-1-entrance-hall), I said I 'solved a simple puzzle found underneath my carpet, which opened a box.' I'm now going to share the puzzle with you, because... I feel like it.

The puzzle was a 6x6 square of letters, along with some words written on the back. The box it opened required a key.

The Letter Square:

LEODFG

NORXIR

GEBKAE

UHYEHC

AINRME

REDBLU

The Words on the Back:

> start at the marked spot. Swan Swims through Water.
>   Not Worried about Such Swift Evasive other Swans.
>   Every Egg Ever is Not cracked.
>   Never Worth Not flying higher over New Experiences.

Where was the key? (You don't need a description of the objects in the room or where they are to find it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is

> start at the marked spot. Swan Swims through Water. Not Worried about Such Swift Evasive other Swans. Every Egg Ever is Not cracked. Never Worth Not flying higher over New Experiences.

If you

> take the capital letters in the message, you get
>
> SSWNWSSESEEENNWNNE
>  
> Assuming these are directions (North, East, South, West), you move in that direction starting from x (the marked spot) The path you go on says
>  
>  KEY BEHIND BLUE CHAIR
>  
>  So is the key behind the blue chair?

Comment: Very close. Pay attention to the specific letters.

Comment: Yeah, PotatoLatte... what letters did you pass when you took those directions?

Comment: changed :DDDDDDDDD (Omg extra letters)